# Pass javascript class to php as json / alternative way

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am beginner in this stuff, but I am learning quite quick so I would appreciate any kind of help.

On example i have something object like

```
function shape(name, size)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.size = size;

    // some functions
}
```

and I am creating an array of this (this is just example)

```
var shape1 = new shape("Square", 10);
var shape2 = new shape("Circle", 5);

var array_of_shapes = [shape1, shape2];
```

I need to send all shapes (name and size values in this case) into php in json or any other format that will allow me to send it to MySQL database

I don't know how jQuery / Ajax works, so I am trying to avoid this way if possible

I am not sure if title is correct when I am calling this a "class" actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you got shapes values in array.. now you can send all values on server using AJAX..

```
$.ajax({
 url: 'http://www.domain.com/xyz',
 dataType: 'json',
 data : JSON.stringify(array_of_shapes),
 success: function(data){
   //server response in data variable
 }

})
```

and on the server side you can receive json data as

```
<?php 

$json_data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$json_array = json_decode($json_data, true);
echo '{msg: "data posted"}';
die;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

kinldy follow and check the link hopefully you will get to understand what you are trying to achieve.
    https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_native_JSON
after value get returned as json you can save it to PHP variable.